# SQL: Use table from table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this as I am running the same Table Valued Function several times, is there a way to get the table from the TVF just once and then run the queries against it to set my variables?

```
DECLARE @RUNS INT
DECLARE @WON INT
DECLARE @PERC FLOAT

SET @RUNS = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tvf_horse_going('Allow Me', 'HEAVY'))
SET @WON = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tvf_horse_going('Allow Me', 'HEAVY') WHERE PosNum = '1')
SET @PERC = (@WON * 100) / @RUNS

SELECT @RUNS As Runs, @WON As Won, @PERC As Perc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    @RUNS = count(*),
    @WON = sum(case when PosNum = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
from tvf_horse_going('Allow Me', 'HEAVY')

set @PERC = (@WON * 100) / @RUNS
```

Comment: Thanks all, I've gone with this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT runs
     , won
     , won * 100.0 / runs As perc
FROM   (
        SELECT Count(*) As runs
             , Sum(CASE WHEN PosNum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As won
        FROM   tvf_horse_going('Allow Me', 'HEAVY')
       ) As results
```

Note the `* 100.0`. This is a quick and easy way to avoid using integer math. Other [less lazy] methods would include: `Cast(won As decimal(5,2)) / Cast(runs As decimal(5,2))` or similar

Comment: I will actually need to start using your CAST method above as I have some more complex stuff to do and the lazy way just wont cut it, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use hash table (temporary table).

```
DECLARE @RUNS INT
DECLARE @WON INT
DECLARE @PERC FLOAT

SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM tvf_horse_going('Allow Me', 'HEAVY')

SET @RUNS = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP)
SET @WON = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP WHERE PosNum = '1')
SET @PERC = (@WON * 100) / @RUNS

SELECT @RUNS As Runs, @WON As Won, @PERC As Perc
```